# PHP Social Networkin Friends Database Table containing serialized data

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I want to develop a social networking site, where users can make friends with other users, and I have the following example table:

Table Name : Friends

id | friends

id will contain the id of the user and friends will contain the ids of the user's friends in one row. The id column will be unique and primary key.

**My Question**

I would like to know if I can store the list of friends as a serialized array as that would limit the friend connections to only 1 row per user as against other methods described in here, which is have  friends table, and insert user and friends id in each row.

During retrieval, I would unserialize the row and put it in an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that but you'll then have to always keep it updated and there is no way to join on that information or search it accurately within a mysql query.

With an app like this you WILL need that data to be available.

If you're not comfortable with the SQL required to join the tables in the proper way just ask for help with the point of confusion / frustration =)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but there is no advantage to it.  It will be difficult to do aggregate functions, for example summing or finding the newest friend will be almost impossible.  Doing joins will be impossible, without unserialising through code and making new queries.  Also, you need to change the structure a bit:

```
Table Friends
ID    |    User_ID    |    Friend_ID
1          4               5
2          4               6
```

ID would be an auto-increment primary key, user id is the id of the user and friend id is the id of the friend

Comment: I think Damchey Lhendup wants friends row should hold the serialized data - not just an ID. Though your table suggestion is, IMHO, a better solution that serialized data.

Comment: This indeed would be neat, but am worried about the scalability part. Wonder how myspace and other medium to large social networking sites besides facebook(they using a social graph or something) store this information.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't concat data (foreign id's) into an single field in an relational database. You won't be able to join/select any data. Instead use:

**friends**
userId, friendId

Comment: Suppose I have 5000 users with each user having approx. 300 friends. Wouldn't that be 1.5 million rows in that table. And as the user list grows, isn't efficiency going to take a hit?

Comment: Friends is an heavy operation for sure, and requires a good approach to make it work (like caching, pre/post-loading). But 1.500.000 entries isn't alot, and it sure beats loading your friends and then doing an WHERE IN(300+ ids).

Answer (score 0):

This would totally break the idea of a relational database.

You could also have a single table - person and storing on the first position the id of the person and the friends serialized after that.

The idea is that you can not make simple queries on those "database structures" like counting the number of friends, regardless to say common friends or other simple operations.

Anyway, I would recommend you to take a look at some [Graph Databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) and consider unsing one for your [social graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_graph)